# Why std::move don't change source variable to default value in default move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, stdmove

I try to understand the move constructor.

I allocate memory in the class' constructor and destroy it in the destructor.

When I try to move the class, I still have a double free.

```
#include <algorithm>

class TestClass
{
 public:
  TestClass() {a_ = new int[1];}
  TestClass(TestClass const& other) = delete;
  TestClass(TestClass && other) noexcept // = default;
  {
    this->a_ = std::move(other.a_);
  }
  ~TestClass() {delete[] a_;}
 private:
  int* a_ = nullptr;
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  TestClass t;
  TestClass t2 = std::move(t);
}
```

Why `std::move` do not change to nullptr `other.a_` ?

I have the same problem if the move constructor is default.

I found the following questions but I still don't know why the move operator don't change the source variable to default value.

[How does std::move invalidates the value of original variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916526/how-does-stdmove-invalidates-the-value-of-original-variable)

[C++ how to move object to a nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484089/c-how-to-move-object-to-a-nullptr)

[C++ std::move a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625565/c-stdmove-a-pointer)

Comment: In your move constructor, you forgot `other.a_ = nullptr;`.  Or by doing `std::swap(this_>a_, other.a_);`.

Comment: In C++14 and after, you'd use [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) to initialise `a_`

Comment: I assume this is some kind of training, that is why you are not using `std::vector` which will do this in best possible way.

Comment: Yes, it's a POC. I want to undersand what the default implementation of the move constructor / assignment and to know when I need to use default or custom implementation.

Comment: @VincentLEGARREC `std::move()` is just a type-cast, and you are trying to "move" to a raw pointer, not to a movable type with a move-constructor or move-assignment operator. That is effectively a copy assignment, so there is no code invoked to actually reset the input pointer to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) just produces an rvalue (xvalue); it won't perform move operation, it won't modify the argument at all.

> In particular, `std::move` produces an xvalue expression that identifies its argument `t`. It is exactly equivalent to a `static_cast` to an rvalue reference type.

Given `this->a_ = std::move(other.a_);`, as built-in type, i.e. `int*`, `this->a_` is just copy-assigned from `ohter.a_`, then both the pointers point to the same object. The defaulted move constructor does the same thing in fact. (It performs member-wise move operation on the data members; note that for built-in types the effect of move is same as copy.)

You need to set `other.a_` to `nullptr` explicitly if you want to define that after moved the object should contain a null pointer.

E.g.

```
TestClass(TestClass && other) noexcept
{
  this->a_ = other.a_;
  other.a_ = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So, what the difference between the default copy constructor and the default move constructor (except the fact that one use const ref and the other a non-const rvalue) ?

Comment: @VincentLEGARREC For built-in type data members, they have the same effect. Both class-type data members, they'll call copy-constructor or move-constructor on the data member, then the effect depends on how the data members' constructors are implemented.

Answer (score 2):

First, `std::move` is just a cast which leads to `other.a_` to be treated as an rvalue. For pointers, a move is just a copy.

This is so, I presume, because clearing the source pointer is not necessary in all cases and it would cause overhead in the cases where it's not needed.

You need to do the clearing explicitly.

Or, even simpler, just use `std::unique_ptr<int> a_`. Then you don't need to define any special member functions and the class behaves as you would imagine.